# Allow others to see picture, but deny access to mysite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, security, my-site

We are sharing parts of our SharePoint 2013 enterprise site with our customers. Security-wise this can be managed pretty well, but I have one problem. Customers do see employee photo & names (next to a post in a newsfeed) and they can also click that name to go to the employee mysite. Browsing to this mysite should not be possible, but, I do want the customer to see the employee picture in the newsfeed, and this picture also comes from a mysite location.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a SharePoint Security Group and add all your customer's
2. Edit your master page and add following script.

   ```
   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HidePhotos('CustomerGroup')");

   function HidePhotos(groupName) {
       var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();
       var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
       currentContext.load(currentUser);
       var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
       currentContext.load(allGroups);
       var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
       currentContext.load(group);
       var groupUsers = group.get_users();
       currentContext.load(groupUsers);
       currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);
   }
   function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
       var userInGroup = false;
       var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
       while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
           var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
           if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
               //Current user is in the group. Remove Photos
               $('.ms-peopleux-userImgDiv').remove();
               break;
           }
       } 
   }
   function OnFailure(sender, args) {
       alert("Failed");
   }
   ```

Comment: Security trimming by javascript is not really security, it is just a "hiding"

Comment: Indeed, i was not looking for such a javascript hack / hide script.

Comment: Ok, i was just putting a suggestion. Also read your question wrongly, sorry.